# show the values of dropdown button in a text box in html

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUfAK.jpg)i want to display the strings in the dropdown button in a text box one after the other by clicking on the dropdown. I have tried but it seems not to work. I also do not want the user to be able to type input, only click and display. Here's my code

```js
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('display');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown0');

mydropdown.onchange = function() {
    mytextbox.value = this.value; //to change the value
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="POST" action="addprocess.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend align="center">Semester Courses</legend>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <label style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 25px;">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;BIOLOGY&emsp;</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="display" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" id="dropdown0" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Click to Select
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8803">BIOL 8803</option>
                            <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8805">BIOL 8805</option>
                            <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8807">BIOL 8807</option>
                            <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" option value="BIOL 8809">BIOL 8809</option>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="click to submit">
        <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I would really appreciate your help, i do not know much of this, a part of it i copied from bootstrap website

[images of what my code looks like when i run it on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIvXT.jpg)

Comment: Try to put this in a fiddle so we can see the actual functionality. I'm a little confused as to why a button tag is there, why option tags are under a div etc etc.

If we can see how it works, it'll be very easy to find out which elements we need to touch

Comment: I just checked it out on fiddle but it looks like crap, it's actually not what i was trying to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/4vd0s3g7/  it was from bootstrap website i got the code for the drop down button from this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#buttons-with-dropdowns  but i am trying to achieve is to put the items in the dropdown and when i click on any one of them it displays the text in the text box beside the button, but i cant seem to get it right

Comment: Check the first answer, the div parenting your option elements really was one of the major problems.

Comment: i have replaced the options tags with buttons but still doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/4vd0s3g7/

Comment: The below answer works already, dont remove the option tags.

Comment: okay i have added readonly but i do not want to use select, i actually want to use buttons coz it looks better to me, is there no code i can write to click a button and the text appears in the text box? coz thats exactly what i want to acheive

Answer (score 2):

With a very quick edit, you can accomplish this. First, we add 'readonly' to your text field.  Then, we get rid of the weird button, change the div to a select, and give it the dropdown0 id:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "addprocess.php">
 <fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Semester Courses</legend><br><br>
   <div class="row"><label style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 25px;">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;BIOLOGY&emsp;</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="display" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" readonly>
       <div class="input-group-btn">

    <select id="dropdown0" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8803">BIOL 8803</option>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8805">BIOL 8805</option>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8807">BIOL 8807</option>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <option class="dropdown-item" option value="BIOL 8809">BIOL 8809</option>

         </select>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><br><br>
   <input name="submit" type ="submit" value="click to submit">
  <input name="reset" type ="reset" value="Reset">
 </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('display');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown0');

    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
          mytextbox.value = this.value; //to change the value
}
</script>
```

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/3axnv2y9/

Comment: would really love to do it using buttons

Comment: is there no way i can achieve the same thing using buttons, i really do not like the way select makes the dropdown look, i prefer the look from button...please help me out here if you can...thanks

Comment: In response to your comment to @ShenoleLatimer answer (I don't have high enough reputation to be able to comment), you can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/yc5kwhkf/ for what you asked, which is just me cleaning up that to put the text where you want.  And, I'll note that the initial HTML you copied has a lot of stuff you don't need: I just edited it to show you what you'd need to do.  If you don't want to use a dropdown, you'll need some other way of allowing the user a choice, unless you just use a single button to iterate through the options they're allowed. Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ebi, this answer is edited over what I submitted previously. It is ***IMPORTANT*** that I mention that the majority of the code I used comes from the answer that "**Grey**" had provided before me. Therefor, if you or anybody else wants to upvote this answer, **please upvote "Grey's" answer** as well or instead.

That said, based off of the screenshots you provided, I think the answer is a combination of "Grey's" functionality, with my "style" tag.

Just like before...

FIRST - I will provide you with a couple of screenshots of my results. The first shot will be with the drop-down menu closed and the second shot will be with the drop down menu open.

SECOND - I will provide you with the code I used, which is HEAVILY influenced (as in copied and pasted) by the answer "Grey" provided.

THIRD - I will explain the code.

Here goes....

******* THE SCREEN SHOTS *******

[image]

[image]

******* THE CODE *******

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Semester Course</title>
    <style>
      .form-control {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
      }

      .dropdown-menu {
        height: 22px;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        border-top-right-radius: 7px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
      }

      .dropdown-item {
        background: white;
        color: black;

      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<form method = "POST" action = "addprocess.php">
 <fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Semester Courses</legend><br><br>
   <div class="row"><label style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 25px;">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;BIOLOGY&emsp;</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="display" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" readonly>
       <div class="input-group-btn">

    <select id="dropdown0" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8803">BIOL 8803</option>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8805">BIOL 8805</option>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <option class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8807">BIOL 8807</option>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <option class="dropdown-item" option value="BIOL 8809">BIOL 8809</option>

         </select>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><br><br>
   <input name="submit" type ="submit" value="click to submit">
  <input name="reset" type ="reset" value="Reset">
 </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('display');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown0');

    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
          mytextbox.value = this.value; //to change the value
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

******* EXPLANATION *******

As in my unedited answer and also the answer from "Grey", you do still needed to use the HTML "select" tag. The "select" tag allows you to have a drop-down menu with as many selections as you like. However, you will notice that in the "head" of the html file I left a "style tag" with some styling properties.

I believe that you commented that you wanted a button and so I styled the selection box next to the text box in a style that approximates the screenshot you sent. Then, I gave the text box a position of "relative" and floated it left. This brought the selection box next to the text box.

The javascript functionality that "Grey" provided is preserved and so you have end up with code that acts like what is depicted in your screenshots and has the relative styling of it as well. If the styling was the main issue, then you just need to mess around with the CSS code that I provided in the header.

If it is a case of you not being too sure about how to code in CSS, I would recommend one of 2 approaches. They are:

1) Visit this link: [www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp)

You may have already heard of this website, but it's great and I learned a lot from it and still use it as reference sometimes.

2) If the example you provided in your screenshots came from a working website, you can actually use Google Developer Tools to look at the code the author(s) of that site used and you can copy what they did and learn by reverse engineering what they did. That's how I learned how to do a lot of what I can do now.

I hope we're getting closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: ebi, I made a little edit to my answer. All I did was supply the correct screenshot for the first picture. I had put the second image twice. Anyway, copy and paste my code and see if it works for you. Please post your results!  :)

Comment: thank you for this, it works in the way you have stated but thats not quite what i want, tell me how you uploaded screenshorts and i'll upload screenshorts of what i am trying to achieve for you to see maybe then you'll get me

Comment: ebi, to add a sreenshot, look in the small window that you use to enter your problem or your answer in. On the icon bar you will see in this order: a "B" for bold, an "I" for italics, a "chain" for links, etc. Click on the sixth icon that looks like a little tiny pic of a mountain. That will allow you to upload and include a screenshot. Be aware though... you can't include screenshots in comments like these, only the original questions and answers. You will have to click "edit" at the bottom of your initial question entry to edit in the screenshot.

Comment: apparently i'm not allowed to add images yet only link, so please click on the both links (the texts in blue at the top and bottom) to view the images...thanks

Comment: please check this out https://jsfiddle.net/yeqbbwfg/2/ i just found this online, and its kinda similar to what i am trying to achieve but there's still a small challenge on how to get the text to show in the text box instead. I would really appreciate your help